# Exception: Jasper Reports integration with java Web App

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want to integrate JasperReports to my Java Web Application: I want to compile my `.jrxml` data with the following coding:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("/reports/report1.jrxml");
```

This code doesn't work. I only get a `FileNotFoundException`.

When i type instead of `"/reports/.jrxml"` a path on my Windows XP file-System, e.g. `"C:/report1.jrxml"` this will work without any problems and the PDF is generated.

When I try

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "reports/report1.jrxml");
```

I get only the path of `"C:\Program Files\eclipse"`.

Does anybody have a solution for my problem? I want to refer to the folder `/reports` in my Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I usually put my reports into WebContent folder. Thus, you can make relative reference to this path.

Also, you must try it running the app in Tomcat or other container.

WebContent
    /reports
          /report1.jrxml

and this must work

```
Strnig path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");    
JasperReport jasperReport=JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path+"/reports/report1.jrxml");
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't work :-(.

Do I have to make any entry in my web.xml or in my application-conext to tell tomcat that my jasper reports are in the WebContent folder?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Sorry but I don't know how I can get the request object. Is this from HttpServletRequest? I have to instantiate the request, but I don't know how this can work :-(. The WebApp runs on a Tomcat 7 Server. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, what type of application are you doing? A Web app, right? And, are you using a developer framework? In this case, you must have an Action or a Servlet and you must recieve the request as HttpServletRequest object but I need more info about your app to help you.